# Dynamic width for div (table like) 

Tags: html, css

I would like to do the following with CSS:

```
name1111 | x | name222  | dateeee | x
name11   | x | name22   | dateee  | x
name111  | x | name2222 | dateeee | x
name1    | x | name22   | daeee   | x
```

I would like every column be the maximum width. I meant, no fixed widths but the longest content would set it. How to do it? It used to be easy with tables, but seems impossible now

Comment: If you're showing tabular data then use a table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a table, so use one.

It's a myth that tables are deprecated - using tables for page LAYOUT is considered bad - using tables for PRESENTING DATA is using the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I see. What can I say, Im a good php programmer but newbie to CSS designing and Ive been told that tables considered deprecated, for 3 years

Comment: I hear it often as well, which is why I described it as a myth - easy to find Correct Knowledge though - just google - e.g. html + tables + deprecated gave me this informative link: http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use : `float: left;` and `text-align: left`.

Comment: They could do but as it's an actual table of data, they might as well use a table. That's what it's for.

Comment: @SpaceBeers, I know but that's what they asked for.

Answer (score 1):

There is ways to do this with CSS, but it would be a lot more complex than using a simple table. A table is absolutely fine in this case. Imagine if you were making a poster in word, yo wouldn't use a table for layouts, but you would if you had a table of data to show. Same thing